# android billing 3 to 5 - PurchasesResult, queryPurchases, getPurchasesList, getSku

Tags: android, android-billing

I'd like to use android billing version 5.
The problem is that I was using version 3 and some things are now deprecated.

I had this but PurchasesResult, queryPurchases and getPurchasesList doesn't exist anymore:

```
@Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
                if(billingResult.getResponseCode()==BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK){
                    Purchase.PurchasesResult queryPurchase = billingClient.queryPurchases(INAPP);
                    List<Purchase> queryPurchases = queryPurchase.getPurchasesList();
                    if(queryPurchases!=null && queryPurchases.size()>0){
                        handlePurchases(queryPurchases);
                    }
```

How can I make it work on version 5?

Also cannot resolve getSku():

```
//if purchase is pending
            else if( PRODUCT_ID.equals(purchase.getSku()) && purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.string.plus_pending, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: did you find a solution on this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He is Google Play Billing Library 4 to 5 Migration Guide
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate-gpblv5#processing-purchases

From your example I would say that you have to call *billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync*. And you don't need to call *queryPurchase.getPurchasesList()* anymore, you will receive List purchases back as Listener parameter.

```
billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(
QueryPurchasesParams.newBuilder().setProductType(ProductType.SUBS).build(),
new PurchasesResponseListener() {
    public void onQueryPurchasesResponse(
            @NonNull BillingResult billingResult,
            @NonNull List<Purchase> purchases) {
        // Process the result
        if(purchases.size()>0){
            handlePurchases(purchases);
        }
    }
});
```